# Can't open project: "One or more lines were too long and have been truncated"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm having some kind of problem with my project that me and my friend is working on. When I try to open the project that I've been working on it gives me an error message saying that "one or more lines were too long and have been truncated" and thus I can't see my code or GUI. When my friend opens the project on his computer (The project is on dropbox so it's the same file) there's no problem at all. I've googled but couldn't find anything. I just did a repair of RAD Studio but no luck. We have 2 forms and a unit that we use, the unit and the mainform isn't working for me but the second form is no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system is on each computer? 32bit or 64bit? And more importantly, which file has the issue? Have you tried opening these files in Windows Notepad to see if there are any issues there?

Comment: Can you try to restore version of file in dropbox?

Comment: @JerryDodge Win7 32-bit OS, my friend is on Win8 probably 32-bit as well but can't swear on it. I have a problem with a unit (.pas) and one form (.fmx) and the corresponding unit. I can't open the .pas files with notepad. Does this mean anything to you? I'd really need to work on the project over the weekend :)

Comment: @pedro.olimpio the restore option looses me like a week full of work I'm afriad :/

Comment: Ahh, so the file has been converted to binary (not plain text). That can happen when you have an astronomical amount of code in there. I've heard of this problem but it's never happened to me, so I'm not sure how to resolve it, other than open it on the *good* computer, copy/paste it to a plain text file, then save that file on the *bad* computer.

Comment: What does 'I can't open the .pas files with notepad" mean? Do you get an error message? Do you see something strange? How big is the .pas file (KB)? I'm also not clear on what "a unit and one form and the corresponding unit" means - is it a single unit plus a form and it's source (meaning two units and a form file), or just a form and the corresponding unit (one unit and one form file). There should be no difference between Win7 and Win8 as far as the files are concerned, and I've not run across a .fmx file that's been "converted to binary" behind my back (as @Jerry mentions) for any reason.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yeah that's probably what we're gonna do but my friend isn't available right now and I had a train ride to kill some time on so I was gonna check if someone had a solution.

Comment: @KenWhite There's no error message, the file "opens" but theres no text at all just empty. I downloaded Notepad+ to test and when I load the files into it, it says "nul". The files are 36 and 16kB. We have 2 forms, for each form theres a FMX file, the GUI and the pas file where the code is. So the pas for our mainform doesn't seem to contain anything. Then we have another .pas file for OOP (I don't know how to explain this really) and this file doesn't contain anything in Notepad either. If I try to open these files with Delphi I get the error of turncated lines.

Comment: 36 and 16kB are trivial as far as file sizes go (I have a single source file that is nearly 300kB, and .dfm files with tab pages that are > 50kb). The `NUL` characters you're talking about are binary markers that Notepad++ displays for #0 values. Are all you see `NUL` blocks, or do you see letters mixed in between them? I think a hex editor is the next step, unless you just go ahead and replace them from your friend's machine.

Comment: @KenWhite I arrived at my parents place, downloaded the same file from Dropbox on another computer and there was no problem, I did the same thing on this computer and it works. I guess case closed :) Thank you all!

Comment: I had the same problem when I moved some code between a 32 and a 64 bit system. I just chopped off the segment at the end of the file that was getting flagged... it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you have Dropbox, and the Restore functionality is available, but using it would cost you a week's worth of work.

If I was in that situation, here's what I would do:

- Copy the current file to somewhere else (My Documents, for example).
- Use Dropbox Restore to get the old version that works.

  - Make a copy of this, because you're going to be modifying it
  - Ensure that you can open it in the IDE.
- Use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to open the two files side-by-side. (If you don't have this, you really should!)
- If they're completely different from each other, you have a serious problem.  If not, you'll see the changes you've made.  Start copying changes one at a time, and after each change, save and try to open it in the IDE.
- At some point, you won't be able to.  That's where your problem lies.  Now you can fix it!

Comment: And finally, stop using Dropbox to share source code files where multiple developers are working... This is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jerry: Agreed.  DropBox is useful for collaboration, but for team software development, source control is a much better solution.

Comment: Thank you, will try this later tonight as my train ride is pretty much over and so is my dataplan. Regarding Dropbox @JerryDodge we're working in different projects and later on adding stuff that we've done to an upgraded version and keep going. So I'll be working v.04 and my friend will be working 0.41 and then we make it 0.5 by combining the changes. We tried SVN but couldn't get it to work :/

Comment: _We tried SVN but couldn't get it to work_ - try a hosted source control solution, like GitHub or CloudForge - then you don't have to set up your own server, which is where most of the work comes in. For a small project with only two users, the cost is minimal (maybe even free). But source control is **essential** - even if you're working alone.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of your project directory.
Search your harddisk for XXXX.pas and XXXX.dfm
Hopefully there will be some temperary files that match - like "mylostform.dfm.~1307~" . copy the newest to your project directory, and rename them to "mylostform.dfm" and "mylostform.pas".

Kind regards, 
Geir Bratlie

Comment: You Sir, is a lifesaver! I will flag your answer as the best thing I've seen this year. Thank you very much!

Comment: I looked for copies of my files as this solution suggests. Apparently in XE2 (and probably greater), there are auto saves? in a hidden folder called __history in the directory of the file I needed. I used it to grab a copy of the most recent file after a forced restart from a windows update corrupted it.